# PhpStorm deployment not uploading composer's vendor folder content

Tags: deployment, composer-php, phpstorm

Although it's not common to deploy composer packages, because they should be handled by the remote composer, I'm still curious...

In PhpStorm when I select my project (root) and choose to deploy with `Sync with deployed to...`, all files and folders get synced/uploaded, except for the child folders of composer's `vendor` folder.

I only see 1 option to exclude items (by name) which contains `.svn;.cvs;.idea;.DS_Store;.git;.hg;*.hprof;*.pyc` and I don't have any `Excluded Paths` configured at the deployment server configuration.
Seems to me there are no mentions about composer related files/folders.

Did I miss some settings which do exclude those child folders or isn't PhpStorm capable to deploy them?
Any suggestions on how to configure PhpStorm to do sync/upload the child folders are welcome.

Comment: If you go to `Settings/Preferences | Directories` you will see that those folders are (extremely likely) marked as Excluded ... (it's not your own code .. and you do not want to see list of TODOs or errors from those files).

Comment: Yes... you're right. But I would have expected the folders to be marked/colored as excluded in the project explorer. If you post your comment as an answer, I can mark it such.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you go to `Settings/Preferences | Directories` you will see that those folders are (extremely likely) marked as Excluded ... which do not not participate in such deployment operations.

---

`vendor` folder most likely means Composer ... and Composer integration in PhpStorm automatically marks all packages as Excluded and then re-adds them back as "PHP Include path" entries (`Settings/Preferences | Languages & Frameworks | PHP`) -- this allows separating your own code from 3rd party one: you do not wish to see/to be warned about any errors/warnings in that code (as part of your code analysis) or see their TODOs in your TODO list, or see matches from that code when you do refactoring or just searching for something (although search is flexible so you can search even there of so desired).

This behaviour is controlled by `Settings/Preferences | Languages & Frameworks | PHP | Composer --> Add packages as libraries` option.